# Cannot import name ContextualZipFile

Tags: python

Here's what I get when I try to install sqalchemy

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==33.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/home/j/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 572, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/j/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2755, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/j/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2408, in load
    return self.resolve()
  File "/home/j/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2414, in resolve
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 51, in <module>
    from setuptools.archive_util import unpack_archive
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 12, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import ContextualZipFile
ImportError: cannot import name ContextualZipFile
```

I have tried installing and uninstalling setuptools.

I have also tried changing "from pkg_resources import ensure_directory, ContextualZipFile" to "from pkg_resources import ensure_directory" in my usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py. However I get the error

```
Best match: MySQL-python 1.2.5
Processing MySQL-python-1.2.5.zip
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/easy_install", line 11, in <module>
    load_entry_point('setuptools==33.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'easy_install')()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 2325, in main
    **kw
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/core.py", line 151, in setup
    dist.run_commands()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 953, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/distutils/dist.py", line 972, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 436, in run
    self.easy_install(spec, not self.no_deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 699, in easy_install
    return self.install_item(spec, dist.location, tmpdir, deps)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 725, in install_item
    dists = self.install_eggs(spec, download, tmpdir)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py", line 876, in install_eggs
    unpack_archive(dist_filename, tmpdir, self.unpack_progress)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 53, in unpack_archive
    driver(filename, extract_dir, progress_filter)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/setuptools/archive_util.py", line 102, in unpack_zipfile
    with ContextualZipFile(filename) as z:
NameError: global name 'ContextualZipFile' is not defined
```

I have also tried directly importing pkg_resources but it still can't find ContextualZipFile. I get the error:

```
NameError: global name 'ContextualZipFile' is not defined
```

I use
python version = 2.7.13 and
pip version = 9.0.1

I am also doing this inside a virtualenvironment

Answer (score 2):

This is a pretty nasty hack but I just commented out the import and `easy_install` seems to be working fine.
Change the corresponding line to:

```
from pkg_resources import ensure_directory#, ContextualZipFile
```

NOTE: It's a system file so you're gonna have to use sudo privilege to change it. You can do that using: `sudo vim filename`.

It's not a great fix, but if you need to get it working in a hurry, this should do the trick.
Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a common bug
https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/issues/252

Easiest way is to use an alternative, like:
yum -y install python-pip